# Trying to create a Binary Search Program, but keep getting this error: TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Tags: python, string, syntax, runtime, typeerror

I'm trying to create a Binary Search Program, but keep getting this error: TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern.

My method is part of class "Solution" and the first argument is a list of ints. The second argument is an int.

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        
        print(type(nums))
        
        if len(nums) == 1:
            if nums[0] == target:
                return nums.index(target)
            else:
                return -1
        
        halfValue = len(nums)//2
        
        firstHalf = nums[:halfValue]
        
        secondHalf = nums[halfValue:]
        
        if halfValue > target:
             search(self, firstHalf, target)
        elif halfValue < target:
            search(self, secondHalf, target)
        elif halfValue == target:
            return nums.index(target)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling your own `search` function, you're calling the `re.search` function that LeetCode globally imported for you. Use `self.search(firstHalf, target)` instead (and likewise the second case).

(You also have other bugs and `nums.index(target)` defeats the purpose of the binary search, but that's not the question here...)